# How I get Azure SSO Login authentication result, if successful login done at azure?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have set up azure active directory with single sign on (SSO) for my application, after login with microsoft email id, I want authentication result back from azure so that I can pass that result to another system and start working on that. How I get authentication result back from azure?
I am newbie to azure.

Comment: could you pls follow up this question if you had further concerns on it?

Answer (score 0):

You have asp.net core tag in the question so I assume you integrate Azure AD into a web application. You also mentioned that you enabled SSO, I'm not sure what you did for it as the [SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on) should be enabled by default when your web app is integrated with AAD.

Your question "want authentication result back from azure", you probably missed some details here about your requirement. Let's have an SSO example. We opened the browser and go to Azure portal, and we sign in with the email account, then we open our webapp homepage like localhost:port/home, if the home page has `[Authorize]` attribute, then the web app should automatically redirect to the `login.microsoft.xxxx` to let you sign in, but since we already signed into Azure portal in this browser, so that we don't need to enter username and password then, when it redirect to the login page, it would ask us to pick the account to sign in, if we pick the account used to sign into Azure portal, then we don't need to enter password anymore and it would redirect back to the home page.

Here you said you want to get the authentication result, it's hard to say if we could get it as you didn't declare what exactly you want, but I trust it probably to be the user profile like who is now login the app, what's role this user has or something else, I could say, I trust most of these information could be gathered by Graph API. It depends on if we have enough api permission to call this API. For example, if the "authentication result" you want to [get is all the calendar event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of the signed in user right now, then we need to have the calendar read API permission(for example). That based on the target API.